# Copy and paste row from one sheet to another in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I am trying to set up an archiving system whereby when a user selects "Yes" from a column dropdown and click an 'Archive' button, all entries that have been selected to be archived will be moved to another sheet. The problem I am facing however is each time an entry is archived, it just overwrites the previous entry that was archived so there is only ever 1 row on the archive sheet. This is the code I am currently working with

```
    Sub Archive_Yes()
    Dim MatchRow As Long, FirstRow As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim Destination As Range

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Set ws = Sheets("Sales Order Log")

    FirstRow = 14
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp).Row
    i = FirstRow
    
    Do While i <= LastRow
       If ws.Range("AA" & i).Value = "Yes" Then
           MatchRow = ws.Range("Z" & i).Row
 
           With Sheets("Archive")
             Set Destination = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
          End With

            ws.Range("A" & MatchRow & ":Z" & MatchRow).Copy Destination

            ws.Rows(MatchRow).Delete Shift = xlUp

            LastRow = LastRow - 1
        Else
   
          i = i + 1
        End If
    Loop
   
End Sub
```

Any guidance would be very much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: What do you expect from the line `MatchRow = ws.Range("Z" & i).Row`? It will always be `i`...

Comment: I was hoping that would cut and paste all of the information upto column Z in any rows that has "Yes" in the archive column which is AA

Comment: Do you want pasting in "AA:AA", or in "A:A"? Your code sets (correctly) last cell **in column "A:A"**... I mean `Destination`. Are there many such rows to be copied? If so, a faster way would be to place them in a `Union` range and copy all of them at once, at the end of the code. If such a `Union` range will also be huge, it should be copied in some steps. I can show you how, if interested... But, firstly clarify the issue of column where to paste.

Comment: The rows to be cut are A:Z and are to be taken from a sheet called 'Sales Order Log' and pasted into a sheet called 'Archive'. There are probably around 200 rows per year that would be archived.

Comment: So, they should be pasted in "A:A" column (of  'Archive' sheet). Is that understanding correct?

Comment: Starting in column A yes and all the way across to Z. AA does not need to be pasted as that is where the decision to archive the entry is made and just contains a dropdown containing "Yes"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Move Criteria Rows Using `AutoFilter`

```vb
Sub Archive_Yes()
    
    Const sName As String = "Sales Order Log"
    Const sHeaderRowAddress As String = "A13:AA13"
    Const CriteriaColumn As Long = 27
    Const CriteriaString As String = "Yes"
    
    Const dName As String = "Archive"
    Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "A2"
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sName)
    If sws.AutoFilterMode Then sws.AutoFilterMode = False ' turn off AutoFilter
    
    Dim srCount As Long
    Dim srg As Range
    With sws.Range(sHeaderRowAddress)
        Dim slRow As Long
        slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, CriteriaColumn).End(xlUp).Row
        srCount = slRow - .Row + 1
        If srCount < 2 Then Exit Sub ' no data or only headers
        Set srg = .Resize(srCount)
    End With
    Dim scCount As Long: scCount = srg.Columns.Count
    Dim sdrg As Range ' exclude headers and last column
    Set sdrg = srg.Resize(srCount - 1, scCount - 1).Offset(1)
          
    srg.AutoFilter CriteriaColumn, CriteriaString
          
    Dim svrg As Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Set svrg = sdrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    sws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    If svrg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No filtered rows.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
        
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(dName)
    
    Dim dfCell As Range
    
    With dws.Range(dFirstCellAddress)
        
        Dim dlRow As Long
        dlRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row
        
        If dlRow < .Row Then
            Set dfCell = .Cells
        Else
            Set dfCell = dws.Cells(dlRow + 1, .Column)
        End If
    
    End With
    
    svrg.Copy dfCell
    svrg.EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
     
    MsgBox "Data archived.", vbInformation
   
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next adapted code:

```
Sub Archive_Yes()
    Dim FirstRow As Long, LastRow As Long, Destination As Range, rngDel As Range

    Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Long
    Set ws = Sheets("Sales Order Log")

    FirstRow = 14
    LastRow = ws.cells(ws.rows.count, "AA").End(xlUp).row
    
    For i = FirstRow To LastRow
       If ws.Range("AA" & i).value = "Yes" Then
            AddRange rngDel, ws.Range("A" & i & ":Z" & i)
        End If
    Next i
    Dim wsA As Worksheet, lastRowA As Long
    Set wsA = Sheets("Archive")
    lastRowA = wsA.Range("A" & wsA.rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1

    If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then
         Debug.Print rngDel.Address, lastRowA: Stop
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False: Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
          rngDel.Copy wsA.Range("A" & lastRowA)
          rngDel.EntireRow.Delete
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True: Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End If
End Sub

Sub AddRange(rngU As Range, rngAdd As Range)
    If rngU Is Nothing Then
        Set rngU = rngAdd
    Else
        Set rngU = Application.Union(rngU, rngAdd)
    End If
End Sub
```

It should be very fast... Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: Thank you for this code. I am not sure if I have some other setting incorrect but this code does very similar to mine, I had two test entries 11111 and 22222. When I archived 11111 it was fine, when I archived 22222 it just pasted over 11111 rather than underneath so the archive only shows one archived entry

Comment: @Strexxin I am not sure I can get you... What does "11111 and 22222" mean? Did it paste only one row? This is what "one archived entry" means? You must know that "Yes" and "YES", or "yes" are different from VBA in the way you try using it... If this is the problem, I can rapidly adapt the code. Can you share a dummy such workbook to make some tests on it?

Comment: There were two test entries, I just called them 11111 and 22222 for ease. What I want for the archive is for each entry to be pasted under the last as it is archived so all data is maintained. What is currently happening however is as each entry is archived it pastes over the previous which means data is lost.

Comment: @Strexxin This cannot be possible, I am afraid. I tested he code... Can you share something eloquent?

Comment: So code cannot be written that just finds the next empty row and pastes the entry into it?

Comment: @Strexxin Of course, it can be done in many ways! But setting the last empty cell in "A:A" was correct in your initial code and I only tried adapting the rest of it.

Comment: That is all I need, for the code to recognise what the last row is and post the entry there, my code was overwriting the previous entry which is not what I wanted. Sorry, it seems that I explained things poorly

Comment: @Strexxin OK. I will adapt the code to differently calculate the empty row in "A:A" and then building a range using it.

Comment: @Strexxin OK. Adapted the code to firstly calculate the empty row and then paste on it. Please, test the updated version, but it should be working correctly with the way you used, too... If still problematic, if you cannot share such an workbook (a dummy one) I cannot understand what's happening in your environment. If you have Anydesk or TeamViewer and a remote connection is accepted, i will immediately understand what is happening... Since the code works as it should on my laptop/workbook, I cannot imagine what's wrong in your case.

Comment: That seems to be working now, I am not sure why the code I originally posted did not work. But thank you for your time today, I have learnt a lot.

Comment: @Strexxin I've just place a debugging line in the above code. Please, run it and tell me what does it return in `Immediate Window` when stopped on that line (`Debug.Print rngDel.Address, lastRowA: Stop`)

Comment: @Strexxin I cannot understand, neither... It worked the same way before modification. Now, if you estimate that you need to process a much larger range of rows to be pasted, the code should be adapted to paste more often. I mean, the building of `Union` range is done rapidly for 100 - 200 ranges, but the code shows down considerably for bigger ranges, that's why it is good to set a limit and paste from time to time and make `rngDel = Nothing`...